# Lax pairs for linear PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, lax-pairs

I'm trying to understand the discussion around equation (2.1) of the paper http://www.jstor.org/stable/53053. It says that the linear PDE $M(\partial_x,\partial_y)q=0$ with constant coefficients has the Lax pair $\mu_x+ik\mu=q$ and $M(\partial_x,\partial_y)\mu=0$, where k is any complex number and $\mu$ is a function.

The way I'm used to thinking of Lax pairs is as operators $L$ and $B$ such that $\dot{L}+[L,B]=0$ is equivalent to the original PDE. This is equivalent to requiring that the equations $L\phi=\lambda\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}=B\phi$ are compatible, where $\lambda$ is a fixed eigenvalue and $\phi$ is any function. Can anyone explain how this connects with the discussion in the paper? What are $L$ and $B$ in the above case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The term *Lax pair* is fairly often used in a broader sense as a pair of linear equations (not necessarily of the form you mention, i.e., $L\phi=\lambda\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}=B\phi$) whose compatibility condition is the system under study. In fact, this notion is occasionally stretched even further, for example, in the theory of integrable dispersionless systems one encounters *nonlinear Lax pairs*, see e.g. [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2122) [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11005-017-1013-4) and references therein.